# How to open a ReactJS Component ('Graph' in this case) on a new page in the same tab without refresh?

Tags: reactjs

When I click on the "Show Graph" Button, my 'Graph' Component renders the data on the same page at the bottom but i want it such that when i click on the button it should render the Graph component on a new page in the same tab.

Render Code :

```
   return(      
    <div className="mainn">
    <div>
      <h4>Toilet Search:</h4>
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.searchHandler}/>
      </form>
      <h3>List of Toilets</h3>
      <table  className="gfg">
        <tr className="head">
          <th>Toilet ID  </th>
          <th>Toilet's Location  </th>
          <th>GeoLocation</th>
        </tr>
        {toilet.filter(searchingFor(this.state.term)).map(developer => (
            <div
              key={developer.uid}
              className="card"        
            >      
                <tr>
                <td className="tid">{developer.tid}</td>  
                <td className="loc">{developer.location}</td>
                <button
                    onClick={() => this.setState({
                        selectedDeveloperId:developer.tid
                    })}
                >
                    Show Graph
                </button>
                <td>{developer.geoLoc}</td>
                </tr>

           </div>
            ))}
      </table>  
      {!!this.state.selectedDeveloperId && (<Graph tid={this.state.selectedDeveloperId}/>)}
          </div>
    </div>

)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to update the current page with the graph?
If that's the case, make your render check developerId first, befor rendering the form and table:

```
<div>
  {this.state.selectedDeveloperId ? 
   (<Graph tid={this.state.selectedDeveloperId}/>) :
   (<div>
     {Here goes your h4, form and table}
   </div>)}
</div>
```

Comment: No, I want the Component to be displayed on a new Page in the same tab such that the older contents of the page are not there and the Graph component contents are present..

Comment: So updating the current page, not rendering the form and render only the graph right? That's what my answer does..

Comment: Oh thats right it did work! thanks a lot for this :)